# MySQL and Python-Insertion

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to insert some values into my table. The code is:

```
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="user_name", passwd="",db="name_of_db", port=3306)
cursor=db.cursor()
readcount=52
sql="Insert into pressure_image(idItem, pressure_val, image_loc, array_time, Time_Stamp) values ('%d', 260, 'a.jpg', 'aray', 14-11-2000)"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, (readcount))
    db.commit()
except:
    print "No value inserted"
    db.rollback()
```

The problem is when I try the insertion command like:

`sql="Insert into pressure_image(idItem, pressure_val, image_loc, array_time, Time_Stamp) values (30, 260, 'a.jpg', 'aray', 14-11-2000)"` the values are inserted in the table correctly but when I try the command as given in the code no values are inserted. So essentially, **constants** work but **variables** do not.

How do I insert variables into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a comma:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (readcount,))
```

Here `(readcount) == readcount`, but `(readcount,)` is a tuple **containing** `readcount`.

Also replace `%d` with `%s` in your query.
As said in the [documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute)

> **execute(self, query, args=None)**
>
> **query** - string, query to execute on server
>
> **args** - optional sequence
>   or mapping, parameters to use with query.
>
> Note: If args is a sequence, then `%s` must be used as the parameter
>   placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used, `%(key)s` must be used
>   as the placeholder.

So, the MySQLdb forces us to use a sequence for `args` argument (which can be of any iterable type) and `%s`. `%s` format specifier is used because values from `args` are escaped and converted to string before formatting the query.

Comment: Tried that too, to no avail.

Comment: Oh thanks thanks! It works! What is the logic behind this btw? Why do I need the value to be a tuple?